# Am I safe mixing types in a Python list?

Tags: python

Are there unforeseen problems in mixing different types in a Python list? For example:

```
import random
data = [["name1", "long name1", 1, 2, 3],
        ["name2", "long name2", 5, 6, 7]]
name, long_name, int1, int2, int3 = random.choice(data)
```

I'm using this code to randomly set several related parameters within a function, but even though Python supports it, I'm wary of mixing types like this in a list. Since the list of mixed data types won't be used for any processing besides variable assignment in and of itself (the variables it assigns to will, but not the list itself), I presume this is fine, but I want to make sure this isn't secretly problematic code.

Comment: Technically array element _are_ all the same type - references (to objects)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

No problem, you can store any type inside a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) unlike in the "olden days" when other languages had arrays that only wanted one type of data stored in them.

Since lists can also store other list, and other compound data structures, along with other object references, processing or iterating through the list may become a bit more complex due to possible multiple layers, than just going through an array in a simple single level iteration. This is also related to [shallow and deep copying](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).

If the code processing the lists is aware of this, I can't think of any problems due to this ability to store different things in a list.

Comment: Thanks. I know I *can* store any data type, but I wanted to make sure no problems manifested themselves that I could simply avoid early on.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano the only problem arising from this is that code processing lists needs to account for this as lists can contains lists themselves, or other data structures. Otherwise, I can't think of any problems with this.

Comment: Well, the code processing the `data` list is all there. It's nothing more than `random.choice`, and it should handle properly as far as I know.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano Agreed, I also don't see a problem :)

Answer (score 23):

The language is fine with you mixing types in a list, but you should know that the Python culture might frown on it.  Tuples are usually used when you have a known collection of mixed types, and different indexes have different semantics. Lists are usually used where you have a uniform sequence of varying length.

So your data would more conventionally be represented as:

```
data = [
    ("name1", "long name1", 1, 2, 3),
    ("name2", "long name2", 5, 6, 7),
    ...
]
```

To put it more succinctly: tuples are used like C structs, lists like C arrays.

Comment: And if your tuple is long or used many places in your code, you may want to define a class instead, so you can name the object at each position within it.

Answer (score 8):

There are no inherent problems in having multiple data types in a list.  Problems may, of course, arise if you try to use that list for something that expects it to be all the same type.  In your example, if this is all you're doing with it, there's no way for it to become a problem.  You might consider, though, using a tuple instead of a list.  By convention, tuples are used when the composition of the sequence is fixed; lists are used when you might add to or remove from the sequence.

Comment: That's what I thought, but since I'll only be using the data in the list separately in their respective variables, I didn't think it would harm.

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply using this to store different possible outputs -- which are following your function's contract of `name, long_name, int1, int2, int3` -- then no problem.

If this is being used by other code that does not know the types within the list and their order, then I do see a problem. A simple example:

```
>>> min(['-2', 1])
1
```