# how to determine an integer in a string list

Tags: python, string, int, converters

i have a problem if i have a string list

for example :

`token=[aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,0,eee,40,ggg,5]`

how can i do to check whether `token[i]` is an integer

i want to see if `token[i]` is integer

i will put it in to a new string list by `i+1:number`

ex if `token[4]=0` i will put it into `result[5]="5:0"`

---

sorry for explain not clear 
first if i have many data 
ex
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K

second i need to convert those data into specific number 
ex State-gov into 2:1  Self-emp-not-inc into 2:2

however i can convert string into number but i cannot convert number into number
ex if `token[4]=0` i will put it into `result[5]="5:0"`

```
for line in lines:
    token=re.split(', ',line)

  for i in range(0,13,1):
    try:
        value = int(token[i])

    except ValueError:
        pass  
    if (token[14] in '<=50K.'):
        result.append('1')
    if (token[14] in '>50K.'):
        result[j].append('2')
    if (value == true):
        result.append('i+1:token[i]')
    if (token[i] in '?'):
        result.append('i+1:0')
    if(token[i] in 'State-gov'):
        result.append("2:1")
    if(token[i] in 'Self-emp-not-inc'):
        result.append('2:2')
```

Comment: I dont think that this question is a duplicated !!!

Comment: I agreed 100%, this is a totally different question. At first I thought, "What, is it really possible that Python is so lame that all the elements of an array have to be of the same type, like original BASIC??!" That's the only way I could explain why someone would think a question asking how to determine if an array element is an integer is the same question as how to check if a string can be represented by a number. Thankfully, [it's not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11387752/1248365). I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `isinstance` if you want to check the type of entry , and if you have multitype elements in your list :

```
>>> token=['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd',0,'eee',40,'ggg',5]
>>> ["{}:{}".format(i,j) for i,j in enumerate(token,1) if isinstance(j,int)]
['5:0', '7:40', '9:5']
```

Comment: but i stll need to convert aaa----->1:1 for example

Comment: @jackson whay ? it doesn't contain any digit ?

Comment: i am try to do data mining i have to convert some information in to number
ex: U.S.A----->10:1

Comment: so based on what logic ? also you didn't speak about string in your question 1!!!

Comment: so i do this 
if(token[i] in 'State-gov'):
result.append("2:1")

if the data is string not number

Comment: based on whatever i choose the number i can set randomly
ex U.S.A---->10:1 Taipei----->10:2

Comment: @jackson randomly what ?? pleaaaaaase add a clear explain to your question !

Comment: @jackson i though your question is not duplicated and i gave you +1 , if you want get a good answer , you need to say clearly what you want , also if until now you find my answer useful you can tell this to community by voting !

Comment: ＠Kasra i explain again can u help me plzQQ

Answer (score 0):

the function [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html), returns the type of the object

```
>>> type(10)
<type 'int'>
>>> type("10")
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: The OP specifies a list of strings. Also, `isinstance` is generally preferred to `type`.

Comment: can you explain simplely i am a new come to python Q

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "13".isdigit()
True
>>>
```